# unity not working with main user (created under previous ubuntu version), working with a new user

Tags: unity, nvidia, home-directory, users

My graphic card is a NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 470, under the previous ubuntu version the driver was showed as installed but not activated, so I dont had unity 3-D. I updated to Oneiric Beta. The new updated driver is showed as installed AND activated, but my account (I had only a single account in the system) only could log in unity 2D, trying to log in ubuntu (3-D) mode only showed nautilus, not any other application, or the launcher.

If I log in guest mode or if I make a new brand account, unity 3-D works, so obviously something in my main account home folder is messing with unity and my video settings.

Can anyone point me where to look ?

I dont think that this is a question specific to Oneiric, because as I say, all seems to work with a newly created account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `unity --reset` on the main account (from a terminal). You just need to log in to the recovery console to do it.

Comment: sorry, just weird I cant use a new line here. Anyway running unity --replace ended with a compiz error message ("Fatal: couldnt open display :0") but pointed me in the right direction. I erased compiz sessions folder in ~home, ran compiz-settings and noticed that unity plugin was disabled (no idea why or when); enabling it and solving all the conflicts with keyboard shortcuts as were purposed did the trick. SOLVED and THANKS !

Comment: @Ign: you can mark the question as solved by clicking the tick (and btw I said unity --reset, as unity --replace does nothing special, it just runs unity).